# jQuery Ajax: html button remains still when clicked without calling up ajax function

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Good day everyone!

Please, I don't know what wrong with this ajax code...
Here is the HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#react").submit(function(e) {
    $('#like').html('Processing..');
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = 'name';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '',
      data: $("#react").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#liked").show();
        $("#liked").html(name + " has been added to your favorites");
        $("#liked").fadeOut(1000);
        $('#like').html("<i class='fa fa-heart'></i>");
      },
      error: function() {
        $("#liked").show();
        //$("#liked").attr('class', 'alert alert-danger').html(name+" could not be added to your favorites");
        $("#liked").fadeOut(1000);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="react" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)" style="width: 40px; border: 0px solid black; color: white; float: left;">
  <input type="hidden" name="aid" value="1" id="aid" style="width: 100%;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="session" value="1" id="session" style="width: 100%;" />
  <button type="submit" class="text-default btn btn-primary pull-left" id="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
</form>
```

The problem is that nothing happens once I click on the above button

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, as you can see something is happening, the HTML is changing to "processing". Since there is no URL to send the ajax to in this snippet there is nothing else happening here. Please be more precise on what "nothing happens" means so we can try to help you.

Comment: The thing is that no action is triggered when I click the button. I'm supposed to either see the button change to 'processing...' and then later have a new value once it is done processing the request with a feedback message.

Comment: Check my snippet again, an action is triggered if you click the button. If it's different for you then there is something else wrong that you are not telling us. Maybe some errors in console? Maybe something entirely else?

Comment: I've switched your snippet with mine and am still getting the same result - Nothing - I suppose the error requires me to sit down and restructure my code blocks, because I have told exactly what I saw and observed. Meanwhile, thanks...